# I can read; but, cannot up- or down- vote, comment, or question

Tags: support, bug, user-interface

Something has happened on StackExchange that has rendered it unresponsive.
I can read but cannot up- or down- vote, comment, or question.
What do I do?
The whole thing fell apart on midnight Feb 28. 
I had to jump through hoops to post this.

Update: NOPE. You're misinformed. Still not able to comment, vote, or answer. Can **only** edit some existing posts such as this one NOW.

**Update: It's happened again. Today, I cannot operate the site normally. Problem with title bar icon links take me everywhere but to the proper link.**

Where can I find out more?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be back up and running now.

During SE site maintenance, the site goes read-only and will exhibit the symptoms you describe.  However, the last SE maintenance downtime that I know of was 19 Feb.  There may still have been something like that to cause the issue.

Comment: 14 April - I can now comment and the functionality of the site has been restored insofar as I can determine today. How (and/or where) can one find out what happened and then what happened? Please edit that into your answer.